# Is it possible to record a video while using imageStream with camera plugin?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, camera, flutter-plugin

I am trying to use the camera plugin for two purposes in my app:

1. Allow the user to record a video
2. Process the video alongside recording with some AI models

I tried to use the camera plugin with two `controllers`.

```dart
  CameraController _cameraRecordingController;
  CameraController _cameraImageStreamController;
.
.
.
// initiate controllers
      if (_cameraRecordingController == null ||
          !_cameraRecordingController.value.isInitialized) {
        _cameraRecordingController = CameraController(
          CameraBloc.cameras[0],
          ResolutionPreset.high,
          enableAudio: false,
        );
        await _cameraRecordingController.initialize();
        await _cameraRecordingController.prepareForVideoRecording();
      }

      if (_cameraImageStreamController == null ||
          !_cameraImageStreamController.value.isInitialized) {
        _cameraImageStreamController = CameraController(
          CameraBloc.cameras[0],
          ResolutionPreset.medium,
          enableAudio: false,
        );
        await _cameraImageStreamController.initialize();
      }
.
.
.
// start recording and imagestream one -by-one
        await _cameraRecordingController.startVideoRecording(event.filePath);
        await _cameraImageStreamController.startImageStream((img) {
          // Do image processing here
        });
.
.
.
.
// finally stop the controllers
        if (_cameraImageStreamController.value.isInitialized)
          await _cameraImageStreamController.stopImageStream();

        if (_cameraRecordingController.value.isInitialized)
          await _cameraRecordingController.stopVideoRecording();
```

The two controllers are for recording and imagestream respectively.
Do you think this is the right approach of using this plugin for my use-case (I was getting some weird behavior when doing this ex. the camerapreview was hung on a single frame many times)? Is there a better way of doing this (even if not using this plugin)?

Comment: is it working ?

Comment: I think it's not working on initializing second camera controller.